# STM32F103xxxx VFQFPN 36 pin package thermal pad, isolated or tied to ground?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, stm32, stm32f10x, manufacturing

Currently designing a PCB based on the STM32F103. The package is a VFQFPN 36 pin package, which also has a large thermal pad. The datasheet for this part does not appear to indicate a pin number or function for this pad. Do I assume it's:

a) An isolated  Pad

b) A Ground pad

c) Something else

Comment: Seems to be the only part in a VFQFPN package. There is a note on a different package: "There is an exposed die pad on the underside of the UFQFPN package. It is recommended to connect and solder this back-side pad to PCB ground." I'd apply that to this package as well, but hmm...

Comment: I'd suggest you ask this on the [ST Community](https://community.st.com/) or contact ST directly. (Don't forget to answer here)

Comment: @Arsenal i had seen that, and for not this is what I'm assuming.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I've done that, still awaiting an answer though(forum), will post on here if forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since created a PCB based on the assumption of the pad being isolated i.e. not soldering it to the board in anyway, with no issues. Albeit I'm not pushing the IC to its limits, but functionality seems okay.